# How to turn 1000 into 1e3?

Tags: python

I want to convert a given number with 0's to be converted to the format with 'e' ex : 1000000 >> 1e6 so far i use this

```py
def test(number: int):
  number, zeros = str(number), 0
  for i in number:
    if i == '0': zeros += 1
  return number[0] + 'e' + str(zeros)
```

Comment: What is the issue you are facing ?

Comment: Works fine for me

Comment: `return f"{i:e}"`

Comment: Uh kind of contradictory since 1e3 is equivalent to 1000, as a numerical value there are the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by iterating over stringified number. Code below iterates from end to start of the stringified number and counts the number of zeros.
Then it converts it to form you want. It also works with numbers like 234000.

```py
def test(number:int):
    zeros=0
    for i in str(number)[::-1]:
        print(i)
        if i=='0':
            zeros += 1
        else:
            break
    return str(number)[:-(zeros)]+'e'+str(zeros)
```

Comment: This will be strange when there is no trailing zero.

Answer (score 0):

You are only reproducing the first non-zero digit. There can be more of them.

Also, you shouldn't count zeroes that are not part of the trailing series of zeroes, so start your loop from the end and break out of the loop.

Change:

```
for i in number:
    if i == '0': zeros += 1
return number[0] + 'e' + str(zeros)
```

to:

```
for i in reversed(number):
    if i == '0': 
        zeros += 1
    else:
        break
if zeros:
    return number[:-zeros] + 'e' + str(zeros)
return number
```

If you are OK with using a regular expression then you can replace the loop like this:

```
import re

def test(number: int):
    number = str(number)
    zeros = len(number) - re.search(r"0*$", number).start()
    if zeros:
        return number[:-zeros] + 'e' + str(zeros)
    return number
```

Comment: @AdityaSinghRathore By this logic, for the given problem `return "1e6"` would have been sufficient.

Comment: it returns 10000e1 when 1000000 is converted

Comment: Suppose your string representation is `S`.
What you have to do is start from the left of string representation of your number and find the first non zero digit call it `a`. 

Call string `S[1:]` `b`, find its length. Call is `n`.
Remove all trailing zeros from `b`, call it `c`.

Your final answer will be `(a.c)e(n)`. If length of `c` is zero, then it'll be `(a)e(n)`

Comment: @Yas-i-ru, did you run the code in the last version of my answer?

Comment: @AdityaSinghRathore, that is indeed scientific notation with one digit before the decimal point. I went for keeping the mantissa an integer. It is not clear from the OP what they need in that case.